# Scrapy ROBOTSTXT_OBEY not working in all cases

Tags: python, scrapy, robots.txt

So I have a Scrapy project set up and I have enabled the ROBOTSTXT_OBEY middleware which is working fine on robot.txt files that are in the following format:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /tools/

But when the same spider on a site with a robots.txt file in the following format it doesn't work:

User-agent: *
Disallow: *?next

This results in pages still being crawled that should be blocked by robots.txt, the by the way in completely valid markup for a robots.txt file.

Just wondered if anyone could shed any light on why this might be?

Comment: I'm not familiary with the middleware but are you sure it is the robots.txt entry format? could it be the warning that the middleware has on its documentation page about multiple concurrent requests?

Comment: Looks like it's due to using the Python standard robots.txt parser which doesn't support wildcards :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy uses Python standard robots.txt parser which doesn't support wildcards.